# Room description of the main chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

Should we have a more descriptive text in the text area designed for the description of our main chat room? And if so, what should it be?

Here is picture of the situation now.

[image]

I have included the mouseover text, because in this way a longer message can still be visible. The size limit for the mouseover is quite large, the entire message from math.stackexchange.com fits inside it:

> Associated with Math.SE; for both general discussion & math questions alike. Just ask; don't ask to ask. Rarely if ever expressible as a ratio of integers. See below for guidelines.

Note that the text will also be visible in the chat room itself, as well as on its [info page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2234/wolfram-mathematica).

Answer (score 10):

*This answer has been written in a such way that you can vote in favor of it or against it, I do not mean to dictate what should be done.*

**Proposal**

Yes, we should change the text and it should be

> Welcome! This is the main Mathematica chat room for mathematica.stackexchange.com. Other than the general guidelines (chat.stackexchange.com/faq) in place, anything goes here. Feel free to discuss most things.

**Motivation**

In my experience, the people that make it to chat are generally nice and polite, so it won't hurt if this attracts a few more of them. Otherwise we can always revert things.

In addition, it seems good to me to have a readable message here, because the [chat page](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=mathematica.stackexchange.com) already seems a bit cluttered and confusing.

Next to that an extra link to this faq can't hurt and lastly the faq says that the topic of the room is supposed to be described in these lines.

Comment: To my latest knowledge, it is not possible to use markdown. So no nice links which will make that we won't have any link to the main site in the whole chat. I'm not sure why, but I use this link very often. The current text was set by me, but I don't mind changing it. It would be very convenient when we could keep a link the the main page in the description.

Comment: I've slightly shortened the description a bit while still retaining the intent. (Hopefully.)

Comment: @J.M. yeah I saw, it looks fine to me :). Maybe the use of the word Mathematica is a bit superfluous, if it is also in the url and in the room title. It also looks good this way on the "chat page" though.

Comment: Maybe I should have added a "Wolfram" for good measure... :D

Comment: I suggest changing "*Mathematica* on SE" to `http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/`. People (including me) use this as a link back to the main site from the chat. Apart from that I agree and voted in favor. I never liked the `BeginPackage` chat title (but not that it bothered me enough to complain, either).

Comment: @OleksandrR. The message has already been changed, the message still includes the url. I will edit the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Oleksandr, as a reminder of sorts: since you've been set as one of the room's owners, you have free rein in changing the room's description as you see fit.

Comment: @J.M. I know, but I thought the purpose of this thread was to agree on how we're to change it. It seemed rude to make any changes without discussing it first. Incidentally, I noticed that the Mathematica.SE logo on the bottom bar also works as a link back to the main site.